# Array not reactive if I modify individual elements of it

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

This is a mutation method inside Vuex store. I'm able to do the commented code and see the change in the component, but not the part uncommented.

Looks like the state is only reactive when I initialize it again with Array(). Otherwise I'm not able to see changes in the component although the state has been changed as I see in the last console.log

```
move(state: GameState, vector: Array<number>) {
                //const piece1: Piece = new Piece(7);
                //state.boardState = Array(4).fill(null).map(x => Array(4).fill(null));
                //state.boardState[0][0] = piece1;
                const size = state.boardState.length;
                const xComponent = vector[0];
                const yComponent = vector[1];
                for (let i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
                    const shifter = xComponent < 0 ? size - i - 1 : i;
                    const shifterPrev = xComponent < 0 ? size - i - 2 : i + 1;
                    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                        if (state.boardState[shifter][j] !== null) {
                            if (state.boardState[shifterPrev][j] === null) {
                                state.boardState[shifterPrev][j] = state.boardState[shifter][j];
                                state.boardState[shifter][j] = null;
                            } else if (state.boardState[shifterPrev][j].equals(state.boardState[shifter][j])) {
                                state.boardState[shifterPrev][j].increaseValue();
                                state.boardState[shifter][j] = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }  
                }
                console.log(state.boardState);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

VueJS is not reactive against mutation such as:

```
vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
```

It has to be done as:

```
Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when working with the complex array of object, I `splice` the array and replace it with an updated one. And Vue can see the change.